# codeigniter project not working on localhost but works if place in internal directories

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello I developed one project using codeigniter which is placed in "localhost/ro" directory. In internal directory "localhost/ro" project works fine but when I move that project to "localhost" only home page shows up and all the other links does not work. I tried placing project in other directories like "localhost/ro123" here also it works perfectly of course I need to change base_url() in config.php. In conclusion I can say that project works only if another directory created in localhost, but if project is placed in localhost it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by does not work? Please elaborate.

Comment: @josephting  only home page shows....when i click on other links page not found error comes....

Comment: Check if it works if you add `index.php/` in front. Eg. use http://localhost/index.php/page instead of http://localhost/page
If so, it's something to do with your URL rewrite rule.

Comment: No. I have .htaccess file from codeigniter which don't need to put 'index.php' in URL

Comment: Then you should include the expected URL output and what are you currently getting.

Comment: @josephting for you I am stating my problem in simple words. I am using linux where directory named '/var/www/html' is present , this is nothing but localhsot. when I put project in '/var/www/html/ro' and in base_url() set 'http://localhost/ro' everyting works. but when I put project in '/var/www/html/' only home page comes and all other links on home page don't work.

Comment: Please be as specific as possible so it is possible to narrow down the possible cause. Otherwise, it's not possible to resolve the issue without identifying the cause.
Example of links should be enough. It shouldn't be a problem to have codeigniter reside in root folder.